# cannot access array javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Does anyone know why I cannot access the array element `location` in the array called `array` inside the last function of `codeAddress()`?

It is the only element I cannot access and the only one which is not created on the first function. It gives me undefined for all locations.

Your help will be very appreciated..!
The array is passed on each function.

http://jsfiddle.net/ang3lo0o/teQEK/4/   The code is in this link

Comment: How about an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? Your jsFiddle appears to do nothing but error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: codeAddress is not defined`. Trim it down to the **minimum** code needed to demonstrate the problem, and put the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id=" + ids + "&callback=?", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
         array[i].location = item.location;
    });
 });
 console.log(array);
```

Two simple explanations:

- Not every `item` has a `location` property - you might check that
- You log/map/whatever the `array` before the asynchronous callback was executed! Move that into the callback function.